# How to put a concatenated data from database to a label

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

My table goes like this:

|  ID   |  FNAME   |  LNAME   |

My code goes like this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE ID = '" & Label18.Text & "'"
 dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
 dreader.Read()
 Label3.Text = dreader("CONCAT(fname,' ',lname)").ToString()
```

Comment: he has already mentioned below in tag that it's a vb.net code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) FROM members WHERE ID = '" & Label18.Text & "';"
  Label3.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

Note : This makes sense when the select returns a single  Cell value

> ***ExecuteScalar()*** in SqlCommand Object is used for get a single value from Database after its execution. It executes SQL statements or
>   Stored Procedure and returned a scalar value on first column of first
>   row in the Result Set. If the Result Set contains more than one
>   columns or rows , it takes only the first column of first row, all
>   other values will ignore. If the Result Set is empty it will return a
>   Null reference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just return an additional column from the database itself.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *, FullName = fname + ' ' + lname FROM members WHERE ID = '" & Label18.Text & "'"
dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dreader.Read()
Label3.Text = dreader("FullName").ToString()
```

Comment: Yes, may be. But the question asked here is different. Error handling is entirely a different thing; and would be in the original code posted in the question too.

Comment: yes, but we should provide error free code. so he may not get error in future also. that's why I was telling you.