# Storing multiple values from SQL Server statement

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following code

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [UserDetail].[User] where UserName = @username and UserPass = @password", con)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", login_username.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash_pass)

 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Suppose that there exist a column name `status` I want to store the result of `status` in a variable.

P.S I am a beginner with VB.NET so please bear with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the statement on a SqlDataReader or fill DataTable. An example with SqlDataReader is

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [UserDetail].[User] where UserName =@username and UserPass=@password", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", login_username.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash_pass)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim strStatus as String = ""
If reader.HasRows Then
    reader.Read()
    strStatus = reader.Item("status").ToString
End If
```

Here is the DataTable version

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [UserDetail].[User] where UserName =@username and UserPass=@password", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", login_username.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash_pass)
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("TableA")
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)
Dim strStatus as String = ""
'you can process the DataTable in a for/for each loop or process a single row as follows
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    strStatus = dt.Rows(0).Item("status").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks....so i use Data reader when i want to retrieve column data and data table when i want to check if rows are return ?

Comment: No it is not so, both support retrieval and count. Usage depends upon requirement. For more details you may refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12509/difference-between-datareader-dataset-dataadapter-and-data.aspx and http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Choosing-between-DataTable-vs-DataReader-in-ADONET-270.php

Comment: Thanks for the article but could you edit your answer to add the equivalent using Data Table

Comment: Check for DataTable version, added to the answer

Comment: @haraman....what is the `Rows(0)`.I suppose it means for first data in column `status`.Am i right ?

Comment: DataTable may have multiple rows, `Rows(0)` represents first row, `Row(1)` will be second and so on. `Item("status")` represents `status` column in the referred row.

Answer (score 0):

If `status` returns a single cell value(*single row in status column*) then you can use following method

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [UserDetail].[User] where UserName = @username and UserPass = @password", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", login_username.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash_pass)
Dim status As String
status = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar), "Not Available", cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        'IsDBNull is used tocheck whether cmd.ExecuteScalar is null or what
        'IIF() is used to handle null here, You can assign custom value for status variable if
        'select returns null value
        'If you dont need to use them its possible to write
        ' status = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

See more about [ExecuteScalar()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007058/3682599)